# Custom post type not being pulled in widget

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-query, widgets

I am creating a widget that displays data from my post type 'testimonials'. The back end of the widget is working fine and displays a list of testimonials and allows me to select which I want to appear in the front end.

However my WP_Query doesn't seem to be pulling in any data at all.

Here is the code for the front end of my widget.

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // extract the widget arguments
        extract( $args );
        $testimonial = $instance['testimonials'];
        $options = $instance['options'];

        // If All option selected display all testimomials
        if ( $options == 'All' ) {
        $args = array ( 'post-type' => 'testimonials',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 20,
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC' 
            );
        // else only display the selected testimonial
        } else {
            $args = array( 'post-type' => 'testimonials',
                            'post-status' => 'publish',
                            'post_per_page' => 20,
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'post__in' => $testimonial );
        }

        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );


?>


    <div id="rotate">
        <!-- WordPress Loop -->
        <?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post() ?>
                <p> <!-- echo the testimonial content, trim white space and strip out any unwanted html tags -->
                    "<?php echo trim( strip_tags( get_the_content() ) ); ?>"<br/>
                    <!-- print out the company name -->
                    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                </p>

        <?php endwhile; endif;
        // reset WP query, restores $wp_query and global post data to original main query  
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>

<?php   }
```

And the code I use to register the post type

```
register_post_type( 'testimonials',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Testimonials' ),
            'singular' => __( 'Testimonial' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Testimonial' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Testimonial' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
        'supports' => array( 'title','editor')
        )
    );
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is not 'post-type' or 'post-status', it is with an underscore instead of a dash:

```
'post_type' => 'testimonials',
'post_status' => 'publish',
```